# Not able to show the add_menu_page icon

Tags: add-menu-page

I am working a plugin development. I want to show an icon on the menu Page. I am using the following code :

```
add_menu_page('pms_rohitashv','PMS','subscriber','pms_rohitashv-main', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'icon.png');
```

`I am using the plugin icon size 16X16` but the icon shown on the menu is `gear icon`. I want to change it with the custom icon.

What mistake I am making in the code

Comment: the icon is on the 6th argument and not on the 5th https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/

Answer (score 0):

You have added the directory name where do you have stored the icon and this should be the 6th argument rather than 5th.

```
add_menu_page(
    'pms_rohitashv',
    'PMS',
    'subscriber',
    'pms_rohitashv-main',
    '', 
    plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'/images/icon.png'
);
```